# Angular 16 standalone dependency injection problem

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular16

Following is my Standalone api calls containing  service:

```js
import { Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { ProductEndPoints } from '../../constants/apiConstants/product-endpoints';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment.development';
import { product } from '../../models/product.types';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ProductService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getAllProducts():Observable<product[]>{
     return this.http.get<product[]>(environment.apiUrl+`${ProductEndPoints.getAllProduct}`)
  }

  getProductDetailById(id:string):Observable<product>{
    return this.http.get<product>(environment.apiUrl+`${ProductEndPoints}/${id}`)
  }
}
```

I also added this service to target component's providers array.

The error I got while injecting it to the standalone component is :

```
src_app_pages_Product_product-routing_ts.js:2 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(Standalone[ProductListComponent])[HttpClient -> HttpClient -> HttpClient -> HttpClient]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(Standalone[ProductListComponent])[HttpClient -> HttpClient -> HttpClient -> HttpClient]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
    at NullInjector.get (core.mjs:8890:27)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:9334:33)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:9334:33)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:9334:33)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:9334:33)
    at ChainedInjector.get (core.mjs:14018:36)
    at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (core.mjs:4608:39)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (core.mjs:4656:12)
    at ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.mjs:11801:19)
    at Module.ɵɵinject (core.mjs:848:60)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1193:31)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1147:17)
    at zone.js:1260:17
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:402:31)
    at core.mjs:10757:55
    at AsyncStackTaggingZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:10757:36)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:401:60)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:11070:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:401:60)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:173:47)
```

Comment: If you're using Standalone, don't import `httpClientModule`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add

```
HttpClientModule
```

in AppModule import Array

Comment: Looks lik OP is using Standalone, so this is not the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an application without an AppModule, you need to configuration it during "bootstrapApplication" by calling provideHttpClient.

Example:

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    importProvidersFrom(
      AppRoutingModule,
      ...
    ),
    provideHttpClient(withInterceptorsFromDi()),
  ],
// eslint-disable-next-line no-console
}).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: There is no need to import the `BrowserModule` in standalone apps.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler thanks, updated the example. unfortunately the migrator did not remove it.